# Is func fread use full buffering mode,how it works?

Tags: c

Is func fread use full buffering mode,how it works?

Does the function fread have to read data only when the buffer is full ?

actually , i want to figure out how full buffering works with the example of fread

i wanna the principle not the usage

Comment: How function `fread` is implemented is not specified by the standard. You need to find the source code of the implementation you use and see how it works example: https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdio/fread.c

Comment: @gulpr: The C standard does specify how buffering is intended to behave, in C 2018 7.21.3 3.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it is very general, he is asking about implementation details

Comment: @gulpr: The question states it wants the principle. You should be seeking how to help people by providing information, not seeking to withhold and deny information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil pardon，I still have another question regarding your answer. I want to fread the last 30 chars of the file,meanwhile the stream buffer is empty, In this case ,how the fully buffered mode deal with this(this stream is fully buffered, and the stream buffer size of 1k)

Comment: @appled: So the stream buffer is empty, the stream is positioned at 30 characters before the end of file, and you issue an `fread`? Then the stream software sees its buffer is empty, so it issues a file system read for its buffer size, 1024 bytes. The file system gets the last 30 bytes from the file and returns to the stream software with an indication that no more data is available. The stream software returns 30 bytes for your `fread`, along with a return value indicating how much data was read. (And, if you try another read after that, you will get an `EOF` or other end-of-file indication.)

Answer (score 1):

> Does the function fread have to read data only when the buffer is full ?

C 2018 7.21.3 3 says:

> … When a stream is *fully buffered*, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer is filled.

So, yes, the stream will have some internal buffer, and `fread` on a fully buffered stream will usually have to wait until that buffer is full before it can complete. (“Usually” because there are exceptions. Notably, if the end of a file is reached, we of course cannot wait for the buffer to be filled because it never will be. The stream software processes this condition and allows operations to continue with the data that is available.)

So, if the internal buffer is 1024 bytes in size but currently has 10 bytes remaining (because 1014 were used by previous stream operations), and you issue an `fread` requesting 40 bytes, the `fread` may get 10 bytes and then (inside the stream software) request more bytes. Then the stream software will try to refill the buffer by requesting another 1024 bytes from the operating system. Once the operating system provides those bytes, `fread` will take 30 more bytes and return to you.

You will not usually see this with terminal input and output because the standard input and output streams are usually line buffered when connected to a terminal. If you write a simple program that reads from standard input and writes to standard output, you will see that it gets the data you type when you press <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, you can change the buffering by calling `setvbuf` at the start of your program. This requests full buffering:

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOFBF, 0);
```

You might also set the standard output to no buffering:

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Then, instead of seeing your program get input when you press <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you will see the effects of the input being fully buffered. The program will not get the input and write it to output until the buffer is full.